# Drag and delete with jquery and php

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

```
    Product Name                            Barcode         Quantity    
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null
    2*WHITER RIN (200 GM)                   8901030295232   null    
    2*WHITER RIN JASMINE FRESH(500 GM)      8901030295201   null


                             Delete
```

This is my table .I need a jquery function to select the particular row in such a way that it should be able to drag or select it and when i click on delete button it should be delete...Can anyone help me out to find a solution in jquery and php

view code

```
     <?php  $i=0;
    foreach($aaa as $row)
    {$i++;
?>
    <tr>
        <!--    <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$i?></td> -->
            <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row[2]?></td>

        </tr>
  <?php 
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: So, can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: i have just able to delete the row by giving a delete button

Comment: Can You show code how You did that so people can give You better advice?

Comment: is your drag-delete functionality 'when the record is dragged outside the table, it is deleted'? Without clicking the 'delete' button?

Comment: no its not able to drag.... Just going through the link which Rauni gave m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code in php. I removed the bgcolor attribute from the `<td>` because it overrides the background-color from the `selected` class.

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
.selected {
  background-color:gray !important;
}
</style>

</head>
<?php
$aaa = array();
$aaa[] = array(1, "Data One", "Data Two");
$aaa[] = array(2, "Data Three", "Data Four");
$aaa[] = array(3, "Data Five", "Data Five");
$aaa[] = array(4, "Data AAA", "Data BBB");
$aaa[] = array(5, "Data AAAAAA", "Data SSSSBBB");
?>

<table border=1>
<tr class='record'>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows">Row</td>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows">Data 1</td>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows">Data 2</td>
</tr>

<?php  $i=0;
  foreach($aaa as $row)
  {$i++;
?>
<tr class='record'>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" class="rows"><?=$row[0]?></td>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" class="rows"><?=$row[1]?></td>
  <td  align="left" valign="middle" class="rows"><?=$row[2]?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="button" id="deleterecords" value="Delete">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // assign attribute selected to clicked rows
    $("tr[class*='record']").live('click', function() {
       // comment line below if you want multi-selected records,
       $("tr[class*='selected']").removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    // remove selected records upon clicking delete
    $("input[id='deleterecords']").live('click', function() {
      $("tr[class*='selected']").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assigning the `<tr>` with an arbitrary class "record" `<tr class="record">`. And the delete button with id='deleterecords'. These are the click and delete functions.

```
// assign attribute selected to clicked rows
$("tr[class*='record']").click(function() {
   // comment line below if you want multi-selected records,
   $("tr[class*='selected']").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});

// remove selected records upon clicking delete
$("input[id='deleterecords']").click(function() {
  $("tr[class*='selected']").remove()
});
```

This is a working implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jPEeq/).
As for drag delete, I'm not sure of the user functionality.

As for your php code, 
Instead of

```
 <?php  $i=0;
foreach($aaa as $row)
{$i++;
?>
  <tr>
```

Add the following class "record" to your `<tr>`.

```
 <?php  $i=0;
foreach($aaa as $row)
{$i++;
?>
  <tr class='record'>
```

And make sure to add the following style and edit it later to what fancies you, it's just to mark which rows have been selected.

```
<style>
.selected {
  background-color:gray;    
}
</style>
```

Also, my delete button has the id='deleterecords'

```
<input type="button" id="deleterecords" value="Delete">
```

Comment: +1 for the dragging comment. Now if there would be a delete box, where to drop an item, instead of a button, that would make sense.

Comment: but when i implement this code its not able to select nor delete??

Comment: Ah, check this http://jsfiddle.net/jPEeq/
You may have missed something. I have the html and JS in there, also note that jquery 1.6.2 and jquery ui 1.8.14 is included.

Comment: i checked that... code... can u tell me how to implement this code as shown above for the view code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://robertfrew.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/drag-drop-sort-delete-with-jquery-jqueryui/